# In python how can you sort a hand of poker (list) and detect if it is a straight or a royal flush

Tags: python, list, sorting, poker

I am trying to create a poker program with python where I get a hand like the one below. What I want to do do is sort the hand and then return true if it True. I need to know if it is a straight as well if it is a royal flush.

```
hand=['Jc','2h','6d','Th','Kd']

def has_straight(hand):

    if hand[4][0] >hand[3][0] and hand[3][0]>hand[2][0] and hand[2][0]>hand[1][0] and hand[1][0]>hand[0][0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

hand.sort()

print (has_straight(hand))
```

need to be sorted and return if it is a straight and/or is a royal flush

Comment: How can you have a straight with 4 cards?

Comment: @Signal: It's a l̶a̶m̶e̶ non-poker-player's straight.

Comment: Strings are a terrible way to represent cards, as you will see when you try to detect hands. Given that, the "isStraight()" function has to first sort the hand...and in such a way that "J" > "T", "Q" > "J", and so on. Then you also have to special-case the wheel (2345A).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, aces can be high or low, depending on what produces a better hand. I will initially value them as 14, but deal with low aces when I get to straights. First, a function to convert a card to a number. I use a `dict` to look up the value of face cards:

```
FACE_CARDS = {'T': 10, 'J': 11, 'Q': 12, 'K': 13, 'A': 14}
def to_number(card):
    if card[0].isnumeric():
        return int(card[0])
    else:
        return FACE_CARDS[card[0]]
```

Sorting a hand is now simple:

```
hand=['Jc','2h','6d','Th']
hand.sort(key=to_number)
print(hand)
# prints ['2h','6d','Th','Jc']
```

Checking for a flush is as simple as making sure the suit of all other cards match the suit of the first card:

```
def is_flush(hand):
    test_suit = hand[0][1]
    return all(card[1] == test_suit for card in hand)
```

Now, to deal with straights. First, we check to see if there is an ace (always the last card of a sorted hand since it is value 14). If there is an ace and the lowest (first, when sorted) card of the hand is a two, we assume the ace is low (since that is the only way you could possibly construct a straight) and check that the remaining cards complete the straight. Otherwise, the ace is automatically high, so we check that each card's value is one higher than the previous:

```
def is_straight(hand):
    hand = sorted(hand, key=to_number)
    if hand[-1][0] == "A" and hand[0][0] == "2":
        # Check that the remaining cards complete the straight
        return list(map(to_number, hand[1:-1])) == list(range(3, len(hand)+1))
        # You can skip conversion to lists for Python 2
    else: 
        return all(to_number(hand[i])+1 == to_number(hand[i+1]) for i in range(len(hand)-1))
```

Now that we have the hard part done, we move on the the royal flush. A royal flush is both a straight and a flush, where the highest card is an ace:

```
def is_royal_flush(hand):
    hand = sorted(hand, key=to_number)
    return hand[-1][0] == 'A' and is_straight(hand) and is_flush(hand)
```