# Specific Order Sorting within a List

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort items within a list in a specific order, most mainly card value order such as 2 being the lowest and A being the highest.

Thanks

Comment: show us some of your work first !!

Comment: Have you looked at Python Key Functions? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions   Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34006574/1164465

Comment: is this what you're looking for? `yourlist = sorted(yourlist, key=lambda x: ord(x))` Or you can change `ord(x)` to `-ord(x)`

Comment: Maybe you could take a look into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525890/in-python-how-can-you-sort-a-hand-of-poker-list-and-detect-if-it-is-a-straight). The first part of the answer should help you with your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use sorted function with a custom key function:-**

```
sorted(string_name, key=order)
```

A custom key function is supplied to customize the sort order of the function. i.e. now characters will be sorted in
`23456789JQKA` this order.

**EXAMPLE**

```
order = "23456789JQKA"
print(*sorted("KA2J32535", key=order.index),sep='')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
223355JKA
```

**P.S.:-** I have converted the result into a string, if you don't want such you can remove the `*`  and `sep=''` from the `print()`

Comment: use `print(*sorted("".join(input_1), key=order.index),sep='')` where `input_1 = ['2','9','4','5']`